# Unsupported type for JsonArray: class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: json, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Updating a subobject with Spring Data for Couchbase

I do this query in the Couchbase console and it is working fine

```
UPDATE `dev_h` USE KEYS "12" SET _data.payload = { "name": "new_name", "language": "new_language"}
```

I want to translate the query in the Spring Data repository

```
@Query("UPDATE #{#n1ql.bucket} USE KEYS "$1" SET _data.payload = $2 ")
void update(String id, Map<String, String> newPayload);
```

but I have this Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type for JsonArray: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the second argument from `Map<String, String> newPayload` to `JsonObject newPayload` ?

Comment: Just to clarify, that's `com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject`.

Comment: the code above should not even compile, there is a syntax issue on the query string. I'm almost sure that Map<String, String> is not supported.I will confirm it and update the answer.

Comment: Link to the related Couchbase Forum post, for reference: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/unsupported-type-for-jsonarray-class-java-util-linkedhashmap/24499